# How to edit a reader in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to work out what the best practise is to change some data in a stream without `ioutil.ReadAll`.

I need to remove lines beginning with a certain character and strip all instances of another.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/pg.v3"
)

func main() {
    fieldSep := "\x01"
    badChar := "\x02"
    comment := "#"
    dbName := "foo"
    db := pg.Connect(&pg.Options{})

    file, err := os.Open("/path/to/file")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // I need to iterate my file Reader here
    // all lines that begin with comment and remove them
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        file := bytes.TrimRight(file, comment)
    }
    // all instances of badChar should be dropped
    file := bytes.Trim(file, badChar)

    _, err = db.CopyFrom(file, fmt.Sprintf("COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER e'%s'", dbName, fieldSep))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", err)
    }

    err = db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Import Done")
}
```

Context:

I'm to importing a large amount (>10GB) of data into a database, it's spread across several files.

My database interface [accepts a reader](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/pg.v3#DB.CopyFrom) to load the data.

The data has non-standard line endings and I need to strip comments (because PG's `COPY FROM` is no fun).

I know the code I've got to edit the stream is woeful, I just can't find a good reference - thanks!

Comment: This may be a silly question, but why won't you just edit the data dump itself (with e.g. sed)? sed should be fast enough to get through a dozen of gigabytes within one hour which is enough for one-time task.

Comment: I"m not sure where you're going with this, since the code is far from being able to compile. Otherwise, maybe the piece you're missing is that you can use an `io.Pipe` to connect a Reader and Writer?

Comment: @JimB Thank you, I'll look into `io.Pipe`. I'm not sure where I'm going either with it either, it's why I asked!

Answer (score 1):

If I was in your position, I'd make my own Reader, and insert it between the source and the destination. That's what consistent interfaces are for. Your reader would work easily on the small chunks of data along as they flow past.

```
Source (io.Reader)   ==>  Your filter (io.Reader) ==>  Destination (expects an io.Reader)
provides the data         does the transformations       rock'n'rolls
```

A library example of such a reader that's made to be inserted between a reader and its client is `bufio.Reader`, that'll let you speed up many types of readers by buffering larger calls to the source, and letting the client consume the data in small bits if it likes it so. You can check out its source : http://golang.org/src/bufio/bufio.go

Comment: For more complicated filters you can make/use a transformer with [`transform.NewReader`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform/#NewReader) from the [`golang.org/x/text/transform`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform/) package.